# C# Identity Authorize attribute region

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identity, authorize, regions

Today, I was owndering if I could use the [Authorize] attribute with regions in C#

I never found a satisfying answer, but I think I found an answer

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
#region testRegion

// GET: /Home/Index
public virtual ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

#endregion
```

With this code, only users with the "Admin" role can see this page

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. Regions are just editor tools, nothing else. If you want to restrict access to a page, just put the attribute on the controller or specific action method..

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

Regions are only for human readability and the're ignored by the compiler.

In your example, the attribute is being applied to the Index() method